Android <include> constraints are not working anymore
I've always worked with reusable layouts with no problem using viewbinding + dataBinding in Android development.
Recently, the <include> tags have had this issue:
When added to a layout, the included tags don't have their constraints defined to their width and height. Instead, the included layout takes the whole layout, and its constraints spots are stuck in the top left corner of the parent layout, making it impossible to connect to another view in the parent layout (also the parent layout).
Any other view that is not a <include>  works as expected.
The project details are:

Android Studio -> Koala
AGP -> 8.6.1
Gradle Version -> 8.10.2
Laguague -> Kotlin

The images attached represent the issue I am facing.


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <import type="android.view.View" />

    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="NOT USING INCLUDE TAG"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/include" />

        <include
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/include"
            layout="@layout/test_include" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>

Button XML File:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="binderModel"
            type="com.toxodevelopment.cinefilo.ui.UIButtonBinderModel" />
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_regular"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:onClickListener="@{binderModel.onClickListener::onClick}"
            android:tag="@{binderModel.text}"
            android:text="@{binderModel.text}"
            tools:text="REGULAR" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>

PARTIALLY SOLVED:

The include tag issue was gone after I installed Studio HEDGEHOG Version, using this project config:
AGP -> 7.1.3
Gradle Version -> 8.10.2
and Material Design 2 (I was using Material 3 before)
I am using the same layout files above.
When I changed the Project Theme to Material Design 2 (Material Components), the include tags started working as expected (having its constraint spots attached to its layout (as the image above shows).
The funny thing is that when I changed the theme back to Material Design 3, the include tags presented the issue again, and only the 1st include in the hierarchy was working as expected.
For some reason, Material Desing 3 is making the include tags below the first include not to work properly.
Another funny thing: When I update the Android studio (including AGP and Gradle version), using the same layout, the include tags stops working as expected again.
UPDATE:
Also working for Android Studio IGUANA Version, using this project config:
AGP -> 8.3.2
Gradle Version -> 8.7
Material Design 2
When updating to Android Studio KOALA and above, the "include" tag layouts presented the issues.

Sorry, I forgot to include the Button Layout XML....
But the problem I am describing is not related to the attributes, as you mentioned.
When adding the reusable layout to the parent layout, using the include tag, the included layout constraint spots is not attached to its layout.you can't select the included layout, clicking on it

Oh, you mean you're having an issue with the layout editor? If that's what you mean, you'll want to tag this [android-studio], since that would be a problem with the IDE.

I am not sure yet, but I believe there is an issue with AGP, Gradle, or Material Desing Versions, because using the same layout with the configs I mentioned, it works perfectly.

In any case, that's where the problem is manifesting, yeah? In the layout editor, not at runtime?

Yes! Layout Editor only.
The "include" constraint spots are not attached to the included layout margins, they are displayed on the top left corner of the parent layout, instead of the include tag borders.
When using the Hedgehog version, it is displayed correctly. But for any Android studio version above the Hedgehog, this issue happens.

Seems like someone else might have run into the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/79175412.
