Included layout does not show its position on the preview screen
On the new Android Studio version, I don't remember exactly which version, but around the 2024 releases. When I click on "included layout", on the preview screen, it still shows the layout design there, But it doesn't show the "location of included layout" on that preview screen.
This does not happen with older versions, like the one I am using is Flamingo. You can see the 2 pictures below to see the difference.


If you don't understand the question, you can watch the 2 videos below to see the difference.
video demo new version Android Studio
video demo version Flamingo
I think in new versions. Android Studio has a setting to turn it off. where can I find this setting? I tried searching on stackoverflow but couldn't find a clear keyword for this

i think you have your videos backwards. In any case, it sounds like it might the same issue as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/79115360. I don't use the graphical editor so I'm not certain that it is, but if so, it seems like a verified bug, either with the editor itself, or maybe with the specialized tooling for ConstraintLayout. You might want to file an issue for it: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new.

I'm sorry, I'll reinstall the videos in the correct order. Also, the other issue is my problem. Maybe I should send this issue to google. @Mike M.
